# I have switched to https, and now my app can't connect to my GraphQL API (but GraphQL Playground works in the browser)

Tags: nginx, ssl, graphql, apollo-client

I used to connect my app (Next, React, ApolloClient) to my backend (ApolloServer) using this url: `http://167.99.145.82:4020/graphql`, and it worked.

Now that I have switched to `https`, GraphQL Playground still works in the browser (https://sketchdaily.club/graphql), but when the client (https://sketchdaily.vercel.app/) tries to connect to it, it returns `[Network error]: TypeError: Failed to fetch.`

Why could that happen?

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name sketchdaily.club www.sketchdaily.club;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sketchdaily.club/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sketchdaily.club/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4020;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate has been issued for the domain `sketchdaily.club` and only this name is included in the certificate. If you now connect to the server using it's IP address the used server name `167.99.145.82` does not match the name used in the certificate `sketchdaily.club` and thus the client will refuse connection because the server can not be trusted.

Just try it out and open `https://167.99.145.82` in any web browser - it will not work. Therefore for HTTPS you have to use the DNS name of your server or change the registration at Let's Encrypt to also include the IP address of your server into the certificate as "Subject alternative name", then you can continue to use the IP address.

Comment: Just to clarify, `http://167.99.145.82:4020/graphql` DOES work. `https://sketchdaily.vercel.app` does not, that's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: @lumenwrites It does not matter if HTTP works for HTTPS access. If you want to access the server via https and via IP instead of DNS name you have to include the IP into the certificate. This just the rule of HTTPS. This also applies to other DNS names of your server. If it is not mentioned in the certificate it will not work.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to access the server via IP, I want to access it via DNS name. That's the part that struggling with. I already have a certificate for it, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Change the URL or the certificate, otherwise it won't work!

Comment: I am actually experiencing the same problem. Was anybody able to solve this?